# Who else was in on Lelouch's Zero Requiem plan?

Tags: code-geass

I was reviewing Code Geass and a subject came to my mind, that I explain below.

> In the ending is stated that Lelouch caused the world to hate him on purpose, so it would not engage wars anymore, however, few people knowed this directly (Suzaku, Jeremiah and CC), and is stated that some people discovered Lelouch true intentions by his death. 
>  On my first view of the anime, I thought that Nunnally and Kallen discovered the real intentions behind Lelouch's plan, but now, seems to me that Tohdoh, Cornelia, Milly and Kaguya as well found the true ambition of Lelouch.

So, was anyone else in on it? Am I correct in speculations?

> Who really discovered why Lelouch had to die?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'll edit to clarify that.

Comment: Your question is currently formatted in a way that'll allow no one to find it :\ The lack of description in the title doesn't help either.

Comment: I made another edit, hope I could clarify what a I meant, with someone had some suggestions about the text, please tell me :)

Comment: Are you trying to ask whether you're correct that people other than Kallen and Nunnally discovered what had happened?

Comment: Since you say "in the end" in your title, you shouldn't worry about in body spoiler tags.

Comment: Maroon, yes that is, I wanna to know if someone else discovered the truth, or it was only Nunnaly and Kallen.

Comment: >! I think in the end it came down to just Lelouch and Suzaku. Given that Suzaku was the only one who actually wasn't suprised at killing lelouch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only ones who seem to be in on the Zero Requiem plan were Suzaku, C.C. and Jeremiah. That much is indeed correct. The rest of the people eventually learned about his sacrifice later on after he died, which is actually a matter of great debate.

But answering the question, those three were the only ones in on it.

Comment: I think Lloyd, Cécile, Sayoko and Nina too did. Their behavior during the battle of Fuji shows something fishy going on.

Comment: And I think even Cornelia knew it. She doesn't look surprised and looks she was waiting for it. That's why she stopped Villetta. And when she cam out and roar to release the prisoners, Jerremiah kinda nodded like everything goes as planned.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are more people involved in the Zero requiem.
From http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Requiem:

> Aside from Lelouch, Suzaku and C.C., several other key characters knew about Zero Requiem, including Jeremiah Gottwald, Lloyd Asplund, Cécile Croomy, Sayoko Shinozaki and Nina Einstein, while others such as Nunnally, Kallen, Ohgi and Kaguya only realized it during and after his execution.

Comment: Please don't leave answers with just a link in them. Copy the relevant parts of the link into your answer. That way, when someone on the wiki edits out the passage you wanted, your answer is still valid. Also, it's just courteous not to make someone read an entire wiki page when only one paragraph of it really answers the question.